# Task and exception silence

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, task

Why exceptions thrown within a task are silent exception and you never know if a certain exception has been thrown

```
try
{

 Task task = new Task(
  () => {
          throw null;
        }
        );
  task.Start();
 }
 catch
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Exception");
 }
```

the program run successfully in a complete silence!
where the behavior of threads is different

```
try
{

 Thread thread = new Thread(
  () => {
          throw null;
        }
        );
  thread .Start();
 }
 catch
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Exception");
 }
```

a null pointer exception will be thrown in this case.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behaviour of that scenario depends on what framework you have; in 4.0, you actually need to be careful - if you don't handle `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`, it will error **later** when it gets collected/finalized, and will **kill your process**.

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine(args.Exception.Message); // somebody forgot to check!
    args.SetObserved();
};
```

This changes in 4.5, IIRC.

To check the outcome of a `Task` that *might* fail, you could register a continuation - i.e. call `ContinueWith` and check the result's exception. Alternatively, accessing the `.Result` of the task (which would also do an implicit `Wait()`) will re-surface the exception that happened. It is good to observe the result of a task, as that clears the finalization flag, meaning it can be collected more cheaply.

Comment: Changed the version number from 5.0 to 4.5 - hope you don't mind. (It'll be C# 5, but .NET 4.5.)

Comment: The remarks section of the [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) had some helpful explanation of the change that happened in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 5):

No, tasks are not threads. Tasks represent a high level abstraction - they are a unit of work that is inherently parallelisable. Threads run units of work.

In your first example, you create a unit of work and then tell it to run itself (how it does so is an implementation detail of Task). Whereas in your second example you explicitly schedule a unit of work (it would appear in a different manner to the implementation of Task).

Comment: The OP is more interested in why `Task` will not throw whereas `Thread` will.

Comment: @sleimanjneidi Tasks will store the exception for when the task is interrogated. In a thread there is no inherent exception handling, it will propagate up the stack until the exception is caught.

Answer (score 4):

The following assumes .NET 4.0, and the using the default TaskScheduler.

First of all notice that the exceptions are raised *inside* the delegates you pass, so they are raised in a different thread, not in the one you (logically) are doing your `catch`. So somehow the exception must be propagated from the thread that executes your delegate / lambda code to the one that started the thread/task.

Note that for `Task`, I think that the library can also choose not to run it on it's own thread, but rather on the calling thread (but I'm not sure if that was only true for `Parallel.ForEach`, etc. and not for a "naked" `Task` object).

For that two happen, two things must be fulfilled:

1. The calling thread is still active. Otherwise there is nothing left that could actually perform the catch.
2. The exception that was caused in the thread/task must somehow be preserved and reraised for you to catch it.

Having that said, both of your examples don't wait for the thread/task to finish. In the first example you're missing a `task.Wait()` (or similar) and in the second a `thread.Join()`. Depending on your test codes timing behavior this may mean that you may never be able to observe the exception from the thread/task (item 1 above).

Even if you add the two calls this is what happens for me (again .NET 4.0):

- **Task** example: the call to `task.Wait()` actually reraises the exception originally left unhandled in the task's delegate (this is what the TPL will do for you internally), it does wrap it inside a `System.AggregateException`, which you could/would see if you'd use something more precise then a flat "catch-all".
- **Thread** example: the exception raised by the delegate remains unhandled and your application exits (unless you do anything to deal with [unhandled exceptions differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx))

In other words I would have the examples as follows:

```
// Thread example
var thread = new Thread(() => { throw null; });
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
// Should never reach here, depending on timing sometimes not even
// until the Join() call. The process terminates as soon as the other
// thread runs the "throw null" code - which can logically happen somewhere
// after the "start" of the "Start()" call.

// Task example
try
{

    var task = new Task(() => { throw null; });
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not getting exception in case of `Task` because you are not waiting for exception in the main thread. You are just continuing.  Put `task.Wait()` and you will get the exception in main thread.

Comment: Very true, but to be fair, in most cases it is *expected* that we won't immediately call `Wait`.