# Task with unhandled exception not tearing down while targetting .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx the tasks which have exceptions that are unhanded should tear down the application.

However in [Task unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648094/task-unhandled-exceptions) the accepted answer states that in .NET 4.5 the behavior was changed to not tear down the application, I am trying to reproduce the crash behavior in MSVS 2013 and I can't get the application to crash while targetting .NET 4.5 (which is expected) but even when I target .NET 4.0 the application still keeps going after I check through weak reference that the task  no longer is alive.

```
 class Program
{
    private static WeakReference _ThrowingExceptionOnATaskRun()
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throwing exception in a task!");
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented");
        });

        return new WeakReference(t);
    }

    static void MyMain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main start");

        WeakReference weakReference = _ThrowingExceptionOnATaskRun();

        CheckIfAlliveForceGc(weakReference);
        CheckIfAlliveForceGc(weakReference);
        CheckIfAlliveForceGc(weakReference);
        CheckIfAlliveForceGc(weakReference);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter something:");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You entered : {0}", userInput);
        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void CheckIfAlliveForceGc(WeakReference weakReference)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is reference alive : {0}", weakReference.IsAlive);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMain();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Main start
Is reference alive : True
Throwing exception in a task!
Is reference alive : False
Is reference alive : False
Is reference alive : False
Enter something:
hello
You entered : hello
Done...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a config element to your app/web.config to keep the old behaviour:

```
<runtime>
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```