# Exception thrown from task is swallowed, if thrown after 'await'

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, background-service

I'm writing a background service using .NET's `HostBuilder`.
I have a class called `MyService` that implements `BackgroundService` `ExecuteAsync` method, and I encountered some weird behavior there.
Inside the method I `await` a certain task, and any exception thrown after the `await` is swallowed, but an exception that is thrown before the `await` terminates the process.

I looked online in all sorts of forums (stack overflow, msdn, medium) but I could not find an explanation for this behavior.

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500, stoppingToken);
            throw new Exception("oy vey"); // this exception will be swallowed
        }
    }

public class MyService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            throw new Exception("oy vey"); // this exception will terminate the process
            await Task.Delay(500, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

I expect both exception to terminate the process.

Comment: That's interesting but I'm curious about why would that behave this way.

Comment: Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981091/1797425) this answer by casperOne, explains a few ways to handle exceptions by tasks...

Comment: His answer doesn't explain why the first is swallowed and second is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure it is? Who calls `ExecuteAsync` ?

Comment: I prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648387/3883866), because it explains the garbage collection concept.

Comment: @JessedeWit this isn't about the GC though. This is a BackgroundService which means it's probably alive as long as the application is

Comment: @TheDotFestClub how do you execute that backgroundservice? Do you use `RunAsync`, `StartAsync`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, it is about the finalizer queue instead. The garbage collector may move objects to the finalizer queue though. _Finalizers (which are also called destructors) are used to perform any necessary final clean-up when a class instance is being collected by the garbage collector._ [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ExecuteAsync` is called from the base class that is a .net code. Its called but not awaited in `BackgroundService.StartAsync`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I execute it using `RunConsoleAsync`

Comment: @TheDotFestClub if it's not awaited then that's the problem - the calling code has already returned before the exception is thrown

Comment: @JessedeWit it's not about that either. It's really about how those methods are called. Yes, *in the end* it's about the GC but only because the Hosting infrastructure works they way it does.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Don't let exceptions get out of `ExecuteAsync`. Handle them, hide them or request an application shutdown explicitly.

Don't wait too long before starting the first asynchronous operation in there either

**Explanation**

This has little to do with `await` itself. Exceptions thrown after it will bubble up to the caller. It's the *caller* that handles them, or not.

`ExecuteAsync` is a method called by `BackgroundService` which means any exception raised by the method will be handled by `BackgroundService`. [That code is](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L30) :

```
    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Store the task we're executing
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        // Otherwise it's running
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Nothing *awaits* the returned task, so nothing is going to throw here. The check for `IsCompleted` is an optimization that avoids creating the async infrastructure if the task is already complete.

The task won't be checked again until [StopAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L49) is called. That's when any exceptions will be thrown.

```
    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Stop called without start
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Signal cancellation to the executing method
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
        }

    }
```

**From Service to Host**

In turn, the `StartAsync` method of each service is called by the [StartAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/6991e2b0e8f7a133208d015dc7d0ca4192523ba0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L38) method of the Host implementation. The code reveals what's going on :

```
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _logger.Starting();

        await _hostLifetime.WaitForStartAsync(cancellationToken);

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        _hostedServices = Services.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();

        foreach (var hostedService in _hostedServices)
        {
            // Fire IHostedService.Start
            await hostedService.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        // Fire IHostApplicationLifetime.Started
        _applicationLifetime?.NotifyStarted();

        _logger.Started();
    }
```

The interesting part is :

```
        foreach (var hostedService in _hostedServices)
        {
            // Fire IHostedService.Start
            await hostedService.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

All the code up to the first real asynchronous operation runs on the original thread. When the first asynchronous operation is encountered, the original thread is released. Everything after the `await` will resume once that task completes.

**From Host to Main()**

The [RunAsync()](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/6991e2b0e8f7a133208d015dc7d0ca4192523ba0/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.cs#L57) method used in Main() to start the hosted services actually calls the Host's StartAsync but *not* StopAsync :

```
    public static async Task RunAsync(this IHost host, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        try
        {
            await host.StartAsync(token);

            await host.WaitForShutdownAsync(token);
        }
        finally
        {
#if DISPOSE_ASYNC
            if (host is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
#endif
            {
                host.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
```

This means that any exceptions thrown inside the chain from RunAsync to just before the first async operation will bubble up to the Main() call that starts the hosted services :

```
await host.RunAsync();
```

or

```
await host.RunConsoleAsync();
```

This means that everything up to the *first* real `await` in the list of `BackgroundService` objects runs on the original thread. Anything thrown there will bring down the application unless handled. Since the `IHost.RunAsync()` or `IHost.StartAsync()` are called in `Main()`, that's where the `try/catch` blocks should be placed.

This also means that putting slow code *before* the first real asynchronous operation could delay the entire application.

Everything *after* that first asynchronous operation will keep running on a threadpool thread. That's why exceptions thrown *after* that first operation won't bubble up until either the hosted services shut down by calling `IHost.StopAsync` or any orphaned tasks get GCd

**Conclusion**

Don't let exceptions escape `ExecuteAsync`. Catch them and handle them appropriately. The options are :

- Log and "ignore" them. This will live the BackgroundService inoperative until either the user or some other event calls for an application shutdown. Exiting `ExecuteAsync` doesn't cause the application to exit.
- Retry the operation. That's probably the most common option of a simple service.
- In a queued or timed service, discard the message or event that faulted and move to the next one. That's probably the most resilient option. The faulty message can be inspected, moved to a "dead letter" queue, retried etc.
- Explicitly ask for a shutdown. To do that, add the [IHostedApplicationLifetTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) interface as a dependency and call [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostApplicationLifetime_StopApplication) from the `catch` block. This will call `StopAsync` on all other background services too

**Documentation**

The behaviour of hosted services and `BackgroundService` is described in [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) and [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

The docs don't explain what happens if one of those services throws. They demonstrate specific use scenarios with explicit error handling. [The queued background service example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) discards the message that caused the fault and moves to the next one :

```
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            await workItem(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, 
               $"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)}.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: AMAZING explanation! thanks a lot. If you have any recommended sources to read more about this topic i would very appreciate it.

Comment: @TheDotFestClub the links to the source unfortunately, and painful experience. The doc examples show how to create a BackgroundService but *don't* explain how it behaves, or why they examples are written this way. I've wasted quite a lot of time wandering why my application "hand" after `ExecuteAsync` finished normally - until I realised that *something* would have to call `Stop`.

Comment: `This means that everything up to the first real await in the list of BackgroundService objects runs on the original thread. Anything thrown there will bring down the application unless handled.` - but the exception *is* handled. It is captured by the `async` state machine and placed on the returned `Task`.

Comment: @StephenCleary it's also returned to `Host.StartAsync` where it *is* awaited. This means that if any of the services fails, `Host.StartAsync` will also fail and the exception will bubble further up. In the end, that exception will reach the [RunAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/6991e2b0e8f7a133208d015dc7d0ca4192523ba0/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.cs#L57) or `RunConsoleAsync` method that's called from `Main()` itself with `await host.RunAsync()` or `RunConsoleAsync`. And I didn't find the exact code for the last `RunAsync` until now

Comment: The op is referring to `ExecuteAsync`, which does have the behavior described by the op (synchronous exceptions are propagated; asynchronous ones are not). Looks like a bug in .NET Core to me; at the very least, it is treating synchronous completion of `ExecuteAsync` differently than asynchronous completion.

Comment: @StephenCleary I spent the last hour chasing the code in Github. I can't even think any more. I *can't* start chasing the calls all over again. Some of those things I've found the hard way, some failures I understood just now going through the code. The [ExecuteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0) documentation doesn't say anything about exceptions though.

Comment: @StephenCleary PS the Hosted Services article should be broken in at least 3 different articles. It tries to show too many things at once. It ends up both too shallow and too confusing

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time reading github issues about this problem. This was the best explanation I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `BackgroundService`. As the name implies, it's useful for work that isn't the primary responsibility of the process and whose errors shouldn't cause it to exit.

You can roll your own `IHostedService` if this doesn't fit your needs. I've used the below `WorkerService`, which has some advantages over `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()`. Because `async void` runs continuations on the thread pool, errors can be handled with [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) and will terminate with an error exit code. See XML comments for more details.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyWorkerApp.Hosting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for implementing a continuous <see cref="IHostedService"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Differences from <see cref="BackgroundService"/>:
    /// <list type = "bullet">
    /// <item><description><see cref="ExecuteAsync"/> is repeated indefinitely if it completes.</description></item>
    /// <item><description>Unhandled exceptions are observed on the thread pool.</description></item>
    /// <item><description>Stopping timeouts are propagated to the caller.</description></item>
    /// </list>
    /// </remarks>
    public abstract class WorkerService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<byte> running = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource stopping = new CancellationTokenSource();

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Loop();
            async void Loop()
            {
                if (this.stopping.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    await this.ExecuteAsync(this.stopping.Token);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) when (this.stopping.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    this.running.SetResult(default);
                    return;
                }

                Loop();
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public virtual Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.stopping.Cancel();
            return Task.WhenAny(this.running.Task, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken)).Unwrap();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public virtual void Dispose() => this.stopping.Cancel();

        /// <summary>
        /// Override to perform the work of the service.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The implementation will be invoked again each time the task completes, until application is stopped (or exception is thrown).
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A token for cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>A task representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
        protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You're not awaiting the `Task` that is returned from the `ExecuteAsync` method. If you would have awaited it, you would have observed the exception from your first example.

### Long answer

So this is about 'ignored' tasks and when that exception propagates.

First the reason why the exception before the await propagates instantly.

```
Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    throw new Exception();
    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

The part before the await statement executes synchronously, in the context you were calling it from. The stack remains intact. That's why you observe the exception on the call site. Now, you did not do anything with this exception, so it terminates your process.

In the second example:

```
Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The compiler has made boilerplate code that involves a continuation. So you call the method `DoSomethingAsync`. The method returns instantly. You do not await it, so your code continues instantly. The boilerplate has made a continuation to the line of code below the `await` statement. That continuation will be called 'something that is not your code' and will get the exception, wrapped in an asynchronous task. Now, that task will not do anything, until it is unwrapped.

Unobserved tasks want to let someone know something went wrong, so there is a trick in the finalizer. The finalizer will throw an exception if the task was unobserved. So in this case, the first point where the task can propagate its exception is when it is finalized, before it is garbage collected.

Your process does not crash instantly, but it will crash 'before' the task has been garbage collected.

Reading material:

- [Finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)
- [Tasks and unhandled exceptions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-and-unhandled-exceptions/)
- [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)