# Why does my background worker deadlock when using Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my project I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with a hosted service background worker.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var result = await _messageBus.Get();
        if (result != null)
        {
            await _dbContext.UpdateData(result, stoppingToken);
        }

        await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Inside my DbContext I do some logic then call `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(stoppingToken);`. On that line the worker deadlocks.

```
await using var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
await connection.OpenAsync(stoppingToken);

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;
await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(stoppingToken);
```

I then changed the background worker to:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _timer = new Timer(async state => await Run(state, stoppingToken), null, 
                                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async Task Run(object state, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var result = await _messageBus.Get();
    if (result != null) await _dbContext.UpdateData(result, stoppingToken);
}
```

This ended up working and avoided a deadlock. However I honestly don't know why this worked and avoided a deadlock. What makes the the `Timer` class different than just using `Task.Delay`?

Comment: How are you calling `ExecuteAsync`

Comment: do you ever call `ExecuteAsync` ? or is some framework calling it?

Comment: None of the code you have posted will block, so won't cause deadlocks. You still haven't shown where `ExecuteAsync` is called.

Comment: How are you sure it is deadlocking? That's not easy to do in .NET Core which has no synchronization context.

Comment: My mistake, `ExecuteAsync` is inherted from `BackgroundService` which is invoked by ASP.NET Core when adding a hosted service to the service collection. To see where `ExecuteAsync` is called see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class

Comment: You shuld to add .ConfigureAwait(false) after your method calls, example: command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false)

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suspect that your code is not actually asynchronous, which will cause startup issues (that can look like deadlocks). It's not documented well, but `ExecuteAsync` *must* be asynchronous. So if you have blocking code at the beginning of that method (e.g., if the "get message from the message bus" code is actually synchronously blocking until a message is received), then you'll need to wrap it in a `Task.Run`:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var result = await _messageBus.Get();
        if (result != null)
        {
            await _dbContext.UpdateData(result, stoppingToken);
        }

        await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
    }
});
```

In my own code, I use a separate base type to do the `Task.Run` so it's less ugly.

Comment: You can add `await Task.Yield()` to the top to ensure it doesn't block.

Comment: I figured out that the user being used did not have permissions to write. When `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(stoppingToken);` was called an exception was thrown. I'm left confused though, why does the method not return it's task as failed with the exception? Instead it just stops and hangs.

Comment: @TravisBoatman: That behavior depends on your db provider. I would certainly expect `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` to throw if there were insufficient permissions. Are you sure it's not throwing?

Comment: @StephenCleary I found out why it behaves this way. The background worker `ExecuteAync` method behaves differently than one might think when it comes to exceptions. It's not very well documented and is still under discussion. See here for more information. https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2017 - https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2363 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871146/exception-thrown-from-task-is-swallowed-if-thrown-after-await

Comment: Oh, right. I thought you meant it actually deadlocked at `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`. If an exception is thrown from `ExecuteAsync`, that exception does not take down the entire process, by design. If you want to exit the process when the `ExecuteAsync` method throws an exception (or exits without an exception), then you'll need to code that yourself using `IHostApplicationLifetime`.